# unbinding events from handler with out framework

Tags: javascript, unbind

I'm trying to unbind all events from a handler with out using a framework, is this correct?  They're both Divs and those are the ids, it just doesn't seem to work.

```
function reply_click(d_850)
{
    document.getElementById("directions").onsubmit = null;
}
```

Comment: is this, by any chance, JavaScript?

Comment: yes it is javascript, or trying to be

Comment: tagged as such - you're more likely to get helpful responses if people are filtering by tag

Comment: ...so it's tagged as javascript cause that's what I'm trying to write.  I'm not sure what you want me to change?

Comment: No, it's tagged as javascript because I edited it to add that tag. I was just letting you know why I made the edit.

Comment: "They're both Divs and those are the ids..." I see only one id, `"directions"`, and if that's a `div`, there's no `onsubmit` event handler. Perhaps you could show us how you are binding the event handlers in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There's [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.removeEventListener) (and [`detachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in IE), but they need explicit references to the functions they should remove. There is no catch-all mechanism. You'd need to store all bound functions separately for a remove-all-of-type-X method when adding them, this is what jQuery does for example.

The only chance left is to rebuild your DOM, which removes all previously bound handlers entirely.